# How to get a null value from database to a checkbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a checkbox in gridview.

```
 <asp:CheckBox  ID="chkStatus"
runat="server"
 Checked='<%#GetStatus(Eval("VaccinationCompletedStatus"))
 %>'/>
```

The function GetStatus is as follows

```
  Public Function GetStatus(ByVal objStatus As Object) As Boolean
        If objStatus = True Then
            Return True
        ElseIf objStatus = False Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function
```

But if Status is coming as null from database then one error is coming as System.DBNull cannot be cast to object.If null is coming from database i want to get checkbox checked false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for DBNull first:

```
If DBNull.Value.Equals(objStatus) Then
  Return False
Else
  Return objStatus
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the TypeOf function to check if the input type if a boolean. If it isn't just return false.

```
If TypeOf objStatus Is Boolean Then
  Your code here
Else
  Return False
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="foo" >
    <ItemTemplate>    
        <asp:CheckBox  runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Eval("foo").GetHashCode() == 1 %>'
                    Enabled="false"
                    Visible='<%# Eval("foo").GetType() == typeof(Boolean) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```